# No muestra la notificación Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

Estoy experimentando el tema de notificaciones en Android Studio. He implementado un manejador de notificaciones de la siguiente manera:

```js
package com.example.notificationexamples;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationHandler extends ContextWrapper {

    private NotificationManager manager;

    public static final String CHANNEL_HIGH_ID = "1";
    private static final String CHANNEL_HIGH_NAME = "HIGH CHANNEL";
    public static final String CHANNEL_LOW_ID = "2";
    private static final String CHANNEL_LOW_NAME = "LOW CHANNEL";

    public NotificationHandler(Context base) {
        super(base);
        createChannels();
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager(){
        if(manager == null){
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return manager;
    }

    private void createChannels() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            //Creando HIGH CHANNEL
            NotificationChannel highChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_HIGH_ID, CHANNEL_HIGH_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // ...Configuraciones extras...
            highChannel.enableLights(true);
            highChannel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
            highChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            highChannel.enableVibration(true);
            highChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            highChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri,null);

            NotificationChannel lowChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_LOW_ID, CHANNEL_LOW_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            //lowChanel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(highChannel);
            getManager().createNotificationChannel(lowChannel);

        }

    }

    public Notification.Builder createNotification(String title, String message, Boolean isHighImportance){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            if(isHighImportance){
                return this.createNotificationWithChannel(title,message,CHANNEL_HIGH_ID);
            }else{
                return this.createNotificationWithChannel(title,message,CHANNEL_LOW_ID);
            }
        }else{
            return this.createNotificationWithoutChannel(title,message);
        }
    }

    private Notification.Builder createNotificationWithChannel(String title, String message, String channelID){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private Notification.Builder createNotificationWithoutChannel(String title, String message) {
        return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    }

}
```

La clase principal **MainActivity** estoy declarando normal mis variables de la siguiente manera:

```js
package com.example.notificationexamples

import android.app.Notification
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener
    {

    private lateinit var editTextTitle:EditText
    private lateinit var editTextMessage:EditText
    private lateinit var switchActivate:Switch
    private lateinit var btnSend:Button

    private var isHighImportance:Boolean = false

    private lateinit var notificationHandler: NotificationHandler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        notificationHandler = NotificationHandler(this)

        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle)
        editTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage)
        switchActivate = findViewById(R.id.switchActivate)
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend)

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this)

        switchActivate.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
            override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
                isHighImportance = isChecked
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id){
            R.id.btnSend -> {
                sendNotification()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification() {
        val title = editTextTitle.text.toString()
        val message = editTextMessage.text.toString()

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
            val notificationBuilder = notificationHandler.createNotification(title,message,isHighImportance)
            notificationHandler.manager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build())
        }

    }

}
```

Cuando activo el switch en **true** debe de activarse la notificacion con prioridad **HIGH** parece que no me está mostrando la notificación cuando llamo al método **notificationHandler.manager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build())**. En realidad no me muestra la notificación, estuve viendo tutoriales y la misma documentación, he probado ya con dispositivos **Android Oreo** y menores a dicha versión pero aun no me muestra la notificación. solo me muestra como un mensaje oculto en la barra de estados. Alguien me podría decir que estoy haciendo mal. Si me podría guiar por favor se le agradecería de antemano

Al hacer click en el botón me muestra una notificación oculta, solo el icono en la barra de estados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al deslizar la barra de estados también me muestra el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me muestra la notificación en la pantalla como muestran en la documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: algún mensaje en el LogCat? Donde esta la clase que implementa FireMessagingService ? llega la notificación en onMessageReceived() ?

Comment: no me muestra ningun error, con normalidad envia el titulo y el mensaje, Pero no me nuestra el mensaje como en la documentación. Solo muestra el icono del mensaje en la barra de estados. es la unica forma de ver el mensaje desplegando la barra de estados

Comment: Aún solo estoy generando la notificación, no estoy interactuando con algun servicio de mensajeria

Comment: Ok @Nik realiza los cambios que indico en mi respuesta, solo asegura que los EditText editTextTitle y editTextMessage tengan valor al crear la notificación.

Comment: Aún está igual, me muestra solo el icono del mensaje en la barra de estados y al deslizar la barra de estados. pero no me muestra la notificación como en la documentación en la parte de superior de la pantalla del dispositivo. es como si estaría siempre en modo privado.

Comment: No te muestra la notificación en la primera posición porque si tienes una creada, siempre se actualizará ahí mismo debes definir otro id.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110181/discussion-between-nik-and-jorgesys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como menciona la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels), "A partir de Android 8.0 (API nivel 26), todas las notificaciones deben asignarse a un canal." , pero si tu aplicación apunta a `targetSdkVersion 26` o mayor no necesitas realizar una validación para generar la notificación definiendo o no un canal, debes definirlo siempre.

Otro punto importante es usar las bibliotecas AndroidX en este caso no usar:

```
import android.app.Notification;
```

y usar lo recomendable para las nuevas arquitecturas que es:

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Implementa estos cambios en tu clase `NotificationHandler`:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationHandler extends ContextWrapper {

    private NotificationManager manager;

    public static final String CHANNEL_HIGH_ID = "1";
    private static final String CHANNEL_HIGH_NAME = "HIGH CHANNEL";
    public static final String CHANNEL_LOW_ID = "2";
    private static final String CHANNEL_LOW_NAME = "LOW CHANNEL";

    public NotificationHandler(Context base) {
        super(base);
        createChannels();
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager(){
        if(manager == null){
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return manager;
    }

    private void createChannels() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            //Creando HIGH CHANNEL
            NotificationChannel highChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_HIGH_ID, CHANNEL_HIGH_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // ...Configuraciones extras...
            highChannel.enableLights(true);
            highChannel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
            highChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            highChannel.enableVibration(true);
            highChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            highChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri,null);

            NotificationChannel lowChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_LOW_ID, CHANNEL_LOW_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            //lowChanel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(highChannel);
            getManager().createNotificationChannel(lowChannel);

        }

    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(String title, String message, Boolean isHighImportance){
       // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            if(isHighImportance){
                return this.createNotificationWithChannel(title,message,CHANNEL_HIGH_ID);
            }else{
                return this.createNotificationWithChannel(title,message,CHANNEL_LOW_ID);
            }
        //}else{
         //   return this.createNotificationWithoutChannel(title,message);
        //}
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder createNotificationWithChannel(String title, String message, String channelID){
       // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
        //}
       // return null;
    }

    /*@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private NotificationCompat.Builder createNotificationWithoutChannel(String title, String message) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    }*/

}
```

---

Importante mencionar que si tienes una creada, siempre se actualizará la misma que fue inicialmente creada, por esta razón debes definir otro id. Para esto puedes definir una variable e incrementarla cada vez que se envíe una nueva notificación.

```
private int idNotification = 0;
...
...
notificationHandler.manager.notify(idNotification++,notificationBuilder.build())
```

Comment: Estoy con la versión de **targetSdkVersion 28** sigo viendo que puede estar fallando pero aún no tengo idea de que pueda estar pasando, la notificación emergente sigue sin mostrarse y los atributos que puse como la vibración y el sonido en la notificación no me funciona, probé con un dispositivo XIAOMI REDMI 7A con Android 9, con un Alcatel que tiene Android 7, y con un motorola que tiene Android 6 y no me logra funcionar...

Comment: Cambiaste la clase como indigo en mi respuesta? Eso debes mostrar la notificación sin problema,  no entiendo a que te refieres con "notificación emergente", en la imagen que agregas a tu pregunta se muestra  una notificación "NotificationExamples", esa es la que se debe mostrar.

Comment: Si cambie la respuesta, a notificación emergente me refiero a esto que está en la documentación de android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=es#Heads-up

Comment: Creo que no mostraba la notificación porque no puse **setSound()**, ahora con normalidad se despliega la notificación, hasta la versión Android 8. Sabes algo del Android de MIUI de Xiaomi? Estuve leyendo que son modificados. Tiene alguna configuración extra que hacer para notificaciones?